# ads.stackoverflow.com is slowing down the site

Tags: support, status-completed, advertising, performance

Dont know where to ask or report this but stackoverflow 'hangs' a minute on loading the ads.

Comment: @Grumpy Consider asking this on the meta site. This question will likely be moved there anyway.

Comment: I didn't know Stack Overflow has a subsite entirely dedicated to the fine art of addition!

Comment: @YiJiang it was inspired by the awesome success of the [jQuery basic arithmetic plugin](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 5):

We have migrated to a new ad provider - you caught us in the middle of deployment.