# ads.stackoverflow.com is dead?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

Yesterday I have noticed that ads.stackoverflow.com is down. The hostname does resolve, but pinging / opening port 80 does not work.

Due to this, https://meta.serverfault.com/q/140/51929 and [Ads that contains erotic images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51736/150311) do not get loaded (for some reason I got to there when [searching for "ads"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ads), don't get me wrong (-:).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!  We've changed the DNS entry so that it at least resolves to somewhere.  Now you'll get the Stack Exchange sadpanda.  Sorry, no ladies for you, unless you count the panda, who may or may not be a lady, it's hard to tell with the state of affairs in panda politics (and, of course, I have no idea whether it is male or female.)

Comment: Tested @ server and it works. My home network still points to the old address, but that's a DNS caching issue that should be gone in a day or so. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow migrated its ads to an ad provider almost 2 years ago ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66000/ads-stackoverflow-com-is-slowing-down-the-site)). All SE sites seem to be using [Adzerk](http://www.adzerk.com/) right now.

I suppose they simply had no further use for the subdomain and shut it down. No ladies for you, sorry.

Comment: How unfortunate :-P Well, why does the hostname respond anyway? It is confusing.